# Postman desktop app is slow on Windows 10

Tags: performance, google-chrome-extension, postman

I had an issue with Postman desktop app and the issue was it became so slow that made it almost useless, I had to restart it after making each request.

Answer (score 11):

To add to this I had a similar issue but it was because I had turned on the Postman Interceptor which was feeding all my browser requests into Postman history. Deleting Postman history fixed all my issues.

Just wanted to leave this here for someone else in case that is their issue as I couldnt find anything on it when I was looking

Answer (score 10):

I have the same issue. None of the above solution works. Basically it has something to do with the GPU.  I tried upgrade the Nvidia video driver but still no luck.

Finally, I found [a Postman support thread that solved my problem](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4594#issuecomment-391601621). All you have to do is to add a parameter `POSTMAN_DISABLE_GPU = true` in your Windows environment variable for your Account (or system account).

Answer (score 4):

All you have to do is to add a parameter POSTMAN_DISABLE_GPU = true in your Windows environment variable for your Account (or system account).

Comment: On Postman menu Help, Disable Hardware Accelerator worked for me.

Comment: what to do for macos?

Answer (score 2):

I found the cause of the issue and though that might be helpful for others as well.
It was caused by Postman Chrome extension! I removed the extension and Postman desktop as now back to normal.
Hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Adding POSTMAN_DISABLE_GPU = true, deleting the Postman history and removing interceptor will make your postman work like a charm.

I had the similar issue.
I saw 20x speed after this.

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar issue, I have opened almost 90 tabs which are not being actively used. After force closing all the tabs, my problem got resolved